# Shorthand javascript object nested property access without "Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, object, shorthand

I have been looking for a way to access a nested level object property without getting a `Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined` error.

I also want to easily default values that might not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have come across anything like that is this:

```js
var someObject = {};
var myVar = someObject?.that?.might?.or?.mightnot?.have?.this?.property ?? 'default';

if (someObject?.that?.might?.or?.mightnot?.have?.this?.property === 'some-check') {
    // this throws no error
}

console.log(myVar);
```